# How to start a batch file from within a perl script and detach from it

Tags: multithreading, perl, batch-file

I want to call a batch file from my script, and want to terminate my perl script with the batch file still running in background, as it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that launching the batch file is the last thing you want to do before exiting run it via `exec`.

> The `exec` function executes a system command *and never
>   returns*; use `system` instead of `exec` if you want it to
>   return.

If you want your script to continue running after launching the batch file you'll want to launch it as a background process. There's no specific way to do that; [perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-start-a-process-in-the-background%3F) lists a number of possible approaches.

For Windows, you could use [Win32::Process](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Console) with the `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag.

```
Win32::Process::Create(
  $process,         # process object
  'myfile.bat',     # application name
  '',               # application arguments
  0,                # don't inherit handles
  DETACHED_PROCESS, # create as detached process
  '.'               # working directory for new process
);
```

Comment: Yes, the batch file is the last thing i want to call, and i wan't my script to end after it calls the batch file. However even with exec it is waiting for the batch file to finish it's job first and then returns.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, the special call [`system 1, ...`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlport#system) is available. This uses Windows-specific functions to create a separate process for your command to run in.

```
system 1, '.\mybatch.bat';
```

Unlike a process launched by `exec` or a regular `system` call, Windows perl will not wait for the child process to complete before it can terminate the parent process; though you can capture the process id (`$pid = system 1, ...`) and pass it to `waitpid`.

Greater control of your background processes are available through the [`Win32::Process`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Process) module, but this may be overkill for most cases.